# Curve fitting from simulated data doesnt work

Tags: curve-fitting

I'm trying to find the parameters of the Ramberg-Osgood equation using curve_fit. Since I'm a beginner in pyhton I created my own data out of that equation to simplify my problem.

It might be, that the curve fit method has problems with the size of the parameters. But neither with boundaries nor with initial values did curve_fit get a reasonable result.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 

# --- Ramberg-Osgood-Function
def RamOsg(sigm, E, sigm0, a, m):
    return sigm/E + a*sigm0/E*(sigm/sigm0)**m

# --- Data simulated with given parameters
E = 70000
sigm0 = 260
a = 0.43
m = 10

sigm = np.linspace(1, 350, 15)      #Y-Data
eta = RamOsg(sigm, E, sigm0, a, m)  #X-Data
plt.figure(0)
plt.plot(eta, sigm, 'x')

# --- Curve_Fit
#bounds=[[69990, 255, 0.1, 5],[70010, 265, 1, 15]]
init_values = np.array([70011, 260, 0.1, 10])
popt, pcov = curve_fit(RamOsg, eta, sigm, p0=init_values)

print popt, pcov
```

The output of popt is exactly my initial values no matter what initial values i chose and pcov does not converge:

[ 7.00000000e+04 2.60000000e+02 1.00000000e-01 1.00000000e+01]

[[ inf inf inf inf] [ inf inf inf inf] [ inf inf inf inf] [ inf inf inf inf]]

Comment: I think you have eta and sigm reversed in your call to curve_fit().

Comment: Well, that helped. But how is that possible, since eta is my xdata and sigm my ydata?

Comment: In your code, "np.linspace(1, 350, 15)" is the X (independent data) passed to the RamOsg() function which calculates Y (simulated dependent data).